# How to get Hardware UUID on windows and mac

Tags: uuid

I wonder if there is a way to get this info on windows and mac? Like the way we can get it on iphone via [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] is deprecated in iOS , for OS X you can get it from gethostuuid() or the registry e.g.:

```
+ (NSString*)getMachineUUID
{
    NSString *ret = nil;
    io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));   
    if (platformExpert) {
        CFTypeRef cfstring = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        if (cfstring) {
            ret = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cfstring];        
            CFRelease(cfstring);                    
        }
        IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);        
    }   
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[for windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fb0d42af-e6bf-490d-860c-3641c22931dc/hard-disk-uuid)
run mountvol command !

Answer (score 0):

Via [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).